# Looking at Matthew 23:34-36 can we interpret this to mean the end of the old Adamic creation with the destruction of Jerusalem in 70 AD?

Tags: creation, adam

Jesus seemed to be focused on the destruction of Jerusalem when discussing end times. The Revelation clearly says these events would take place SOON. If we connect what Jesus said in the gospels to Revelation, it seems that the old “Adamic” creation, from Abel to Zechariah, was judged and done away with after the Resurrection. Jesus said he was the first born of the new creation.
So it seems the end of the old creation culminated at the destruction of Jerusalem  in 70AD. Would this be an accurate interpretation of events?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: I've been searching my Bible for any scripture where Jesus said "he was the first born of the new creation."  Firstborn from the dead, yes. Firstborn of all creation, yes.  But the first born of the new creation?  Please give us the Bible verses to back that up, and also where you have biblical support for saying the old "Adamic" creation, from Abel to Zechariah, was judged and done away with after the resurrection.  That might encourage people to attempt an answer!

Comment: The New Creation is spiritual, for now ; and shall be substantial upon the creation of new heavens and new earth appropriate to that spiritual life, begotten of the Father who 'brings many sons unto glory'. The old creation subsists until that culmination of the New Creation in glorious and full expression, the final redemption begun in Christ Jesus. The old creation is judged in the Cross of Christ. But its substance still exists until the return of Christ and the establishment of newly created accompaniment to the new birth. Up-voted +1. Answered below.

Answer (score 2):

The New Creation is spiritual, for now ; and shall be substantial upon the creation of new heavens and new earth appropriate to that spiritual life, begotten of the Father who 'brings many sons unto glory'.

The old creation subsists until that culmination of the New Creation in glorious and full expression, the final redemption begun in Christ Jesus.

The old creation is judged in the Cross of Christ. But its substance still exists until the return of Christ and the establishment of newly created accompaniment to the new birth.

Answer (score 0):

> OP: Jesus seemed to be focused on the destruction of Jerusalem when discussing end times.

Yes, some believe all prophecy, especially Mt. 24, was fulfilled then.

> OP: ... Jesus said he was the first born of the new creation. So it seems the end of the old creation culminated at the destruction of Jerusalem in 70AD. Would this be an accurate interpretation of events?

Not really.  We are all still born into/with a sin nature.  Christ said you must be born again (by flesh and by Spirit (Jn 3:3)).  That hasn’t changed.  In other words, we are all still born “in Adam”, regardless of one’s eschatology regarding the temple destruction and its meaning in 70AD.

> And so it is written, The first man Adam was made a living soul; the last Adam was made a quickening spirit.  … And as we have borne the image of the earthy, we shall also bear the image of the heavenly.  1 Cor 15:45, 49

At the same time, however, there is a “new” beginning; again, regardless of 70AD.  The beginning is in Christ as we are His body, the church.

> And he is the head of the body, the church: who is the beginning, the firstborn from the dead; that in all things he might have the preeminence. Col 1:18

Christ is the first fruit, the firstborn, the beginning.

PS Some confusion may arise as certain Greek words were translated the same, even though the two words are different.

> But he spake of the temple of his body. Jn 2:21

Temple is “naos”.  It means the Holy of Holies and for NT purposes Christ’s body (church).

> While he answered for himself, Neither against the law of the Jews, neither against the temple, nor yet against Caesar, have I offended any thing at all. Acts 25:8

Temple is “hieron”.  It means the temple in Jerusalem.

So, while “hieron” is destroyed, it is not the “naos”.  And it is not the old nature that is yet destroyed, but for some, there is the new nature, new creature.

> Therefore if any man be in Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are become new. 2 Cor 5:17

Answer (score 0):

**Out with the Old; In with the New** This is an interesting topic! In Matthew 23, Jesus laid the groundwork for the descriptive Olivet Discourse in chapter 24-25.  This oration dealt with the Destruction of Judea and in particular, the Temple, as you noted.

However, let me humbly point out that a common mistake was committed in this questioning: Jumbling separate scriptures together, and overlooking the context of each. For a basic rule of Hermeneutics (Rules of exposition) is to always consider the context of a verse. Sometimes, even if the same "word" is used, it means different things because of the different Context.

**Old Covenant** The Destruction of the Temple *did* signal the end of the Old Mosaic Covenant of Law. (70 A.D.) Christ now reigns under the New Covenant of Grace and Faith.

> The Law was given by Moses, but grace and truth came by Jesus Christ. (John 1:17)

> Verily I say unto you, This generation shall not pass, till all these things be fulfilled. (Matthew 24:34)

**Revelation** The Book of Revelation is a book that fits in a different *genre* of biblical literature. It is an Apocalypse. It cannot be lumped together with the Gospel of Matthew which is a Biographical work. It is suggested that it be studied separately from the topic raised in Matthew 23 and 24.

**Done Away With** What was done away with by the Death and Resurrection of Christ was *the Old Covenant*, not the old Creation.  The Law was nailed to the cross, along with all of our "rap sheets" (our condemnation). This was hinted at when Jesus told the Woman at the well that neither at Samaria's mountain, nor in Jerusalem (Mount Zion), would there be a center of worship! *But the true worshippers would worship in Spirit and in truth* (John 4:23). And that can be done anywhere, without the Mosaic regulations or Temple rituals...or Samaritan sacrifices.

In a sense, *the old man is crucified with Christ*, the old nature of man is done away with in salvation, as Paul noted.  But this is different than what you seem to be mentioning.  It has nothing to do with the physical Creation.  That is yet future.

The Earth still "groans", awaiting for its redemption that will occur at the Second Coming! (1 Corinthians 15, 2 Peter 3:7-13). That is the **Blessed Hope** of every Christian.

Keep studying the Bible, it's great for the soul!